# Why do I return undefined for a large number but not a small one? (Fibonacci Sequence Sum)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, fibonacci

this code right here does work, but i don't quite understand why.

if i remove the interior return statement and keep only the one at the end, it will return the correct sum (44) for `console.log(evenFibonnacisSum(100))`, but undefined for `console.log(evenFibonnacisSum(4000000))`.

if i remove the exterior return statement and keep the one inside the if statement, it will return undefined for `console.log(evenFibonnacisSum(100))` but the correct sum (46000000 or so) for `console.log(evenFibonnacisSum(4000000))`.

```
function evenFibonnacisSum(upperlimit){
  let evenSum = 0  
  let seq = [0, 1]
  for(i=0; i<=upperlimit; i++) {
    if(evenSum<upperlimit) {
      let next = seq[i]+seq[i+1];
      seq.push(next)
      if(seq[i]%2 === 0 && seq[i]<upperlimit) {
        evenSum += seq[i]
       }
    } else {      
      return evenSum
    }
  }
  return evenSum
}

console.log(evenFibonnacisSum(100))

console.log(evenFibonnacisSum(4000000))
```

it's not a huge problem, but it's really unintuitive. anyone have any insight into why this might be?

Comment: You're probably running into the limits of floating point precision.

Comment: @Barmar for 100?

Comment: @Sean No, for really large numbers.

Comment: What environment are you running it in where you see the first behavior (undefined for large values when removing the internal return)? Curiously, if I try that on JSBin, it gives me a warning in the console about a *potential* infinite loop. Maybe some silent, 'helpful' feature of your environment? It still appears to give the right behavior here, though: https://jsbin.com/vaxehireta/edit?js,console,output

Comment: If you remove the second `return` statement, then it doesn't return anything if the `else` block never executes, so you get `undefined`

Comment: I get the same result with and without the inner `return`.

Comment: @Ben i was running it in the VScode terminal using the Code Runner extension. you might be onto something with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the interior return and pass in a large `upperlimit`, then it will attempt to execute the loop too many times.  Your environment realizes that it is taking too long and aborts the function.

If you remove the external return then for `100` you never hit the interior return because the correct answer has `evenSum < upperlimit`.

I would suggest coding it like this instead:

```
function evenFibonnacisSum(upperlimit){
  let evenSum = 0
  let seq = [0, 1]
  i = 0  
  while(seq[i] < upperlimit) {
    let next = seq[i]+seq[i+1];
    seq.push(next)
    if(seq[i]%2 === 0) {
      evenSum += seq[i]
    } 
    i++
  }
  return evenSum
}
```